# Display the contents of a textfield in extjs4

Tags: extjs

I want to display the value of a textfield near the textfield box if it has some contents and display nothing when it is empty. How is it possible ?

Comment: and what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of options. For example, you can use a Ext.dom.Element:

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
    Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Text', {
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        fieldLabel: 'Field',
        afterSubTpl: '<div id="my-field-sub-tpl"></div>',
        listeners: {
            change: function(field, val) {
                Ext.get('my-field-sub-tpl').setHTML(val);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

See on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hDRqS/

But it is better to do it as a plugin for the field - then it can be applied to any field of your application: http://jsfiddle.net/hDRqS/1/